# ORMLite Android Sub queries for filter item using multiple values

Tags: android, android-sqlite, ormlite

I have DB object like below and I am able to filter items which equal to given single value but I want to do it with multiple value like below :

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "item_list")
public class ItemDB {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private Long id;

    @DatabaseField
    private String mobileNumber;

    @DatabaseField
    private String itemCode;

    @DatabaseField
    private String lTNumber;

    public ItemDB() {
    }
}
```

I need to filter item which equals to given `mobileNumber`, `itemCode` and `LTNumber`. How can I filter `item_list` using these three value

Comment: I think this addresses this http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_3.html#QueryBuilder-Basics
Something like : 

  
queryBuilder.where()
  .eq(ItemDB.MOBILE, "9999999")
  .and()
  .eq(ItemDB.ITEM_CODE, "AX123");

Comment: @don Yes your correct, thank you this is the correct answer